# Is the student badge awarded only when your very first post is up voted?

Tags: support, badges

For the student badge on Stack Overflow, does it have to be your *first* ever post with one upvote, or just any? It is not very specific.

Comment: In the other case, I think it would say something like *"Earn a score of 1 or more in your first/first ever published question"* or *"First ever published question has a score of 1 or more"*. I find it pretty intuitive as it is right now. In this case, it is like *"Achieve a question with a score of 1 or more"*.

Comment: @S.Dre It says "First question with score of 1 or more"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's awarded when `COUNT(posts where upvotes > 0) > 0` ("just any").

Easy to prove: go to [the Student badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student), find [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10981847/dan) who was recently awarded the badge. That user's [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726437/prettier-config-on-css-vs-code-id-block) was posted a year ago; the question that got the upvote & the badge [was from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398690/hover-animation-backwards).

Comment: Why not just `posts where upvotes > 0`?

Comment: @justanotherguy: because that gives you a list of posts. What would you do with that list? Having a badge or not having a badge is a yes/no question, so you want a true/false result.

Comment: Ah! Right. Gotta brush up on my SQL